# python to make changes in existing file

Tags: python, stdout

I have a code which parses a text file and prints it on `stdout` but I need to **make changes on the existing text file** and **preserving the indentation also**

Here's my code:

```
import re
import collections
class Group:
    def __init__(self):
        self.members = []
        self.text = []

with open('text1.txt') as f:
    groups = collections.defaultdict(Group)
    group_pattern = re.compile(r'^(\S+)\((.*)\)$')
    current_group = None
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        m = group_pattern.match(line)
        if m:    # this is a group definition line
            group_name, group_members = m.groups()
            groups[group_name].members += filter(lambda x: x not in groups[group_name].members , group_members.split(','))
            current_group = group_name
        else:
            if (current_group is not None) and (len(line) > 0):
                groups[current_group].text.append(line)

for group_name, group in groups.items():
    print "%s(%s)" % (group_name, ','.join(group.members))
    print '\n'.join(group.text)
    print
```

INPUT Text.txt

```
   Car(skoda,audi,benz,bmw)
  The above mentioned cars are sedan type and gives long rides efficient
 ......

Car(Rangerover,audi,Hummer)
SUV cars are used for family time and spacious.
```

Expected Output Text.txt

```
   Car(skoda,audi,benz,bmw,Rangerover,Hummer)
  The above mentioned cars are sedan type and gives long rides efficient
 ......


SUV cars are used for family time and spacious.
```

But getting output as:

```
Car(skoda,audi,benz,bmw,Rangerover,Hummer)
The above mentioned cars are sedan type and gives long rides efficient
......


SUV cars are used for family time and spacious.
```

How do i preserve the indentation?

Comment: Simply open the file in write mode, and then write to it in the for loop.

Comment: so does it will replace the old with new output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why the indentation is lost in your code, is that you first strip the line for whitespace before adding it to the dict.

```
 for line in f:
    line = line.strip()
```

I've rewritten the code so that it in the first loop finds all the members of the groups, and in the second loop appends the members to the first instance of the group and then deletes other instances of the same group.
Its a little hacky, but I'm sure you'll be able to make it work quicker.

```
import re
import collections
class Group:
    def __init__(self):
        self.members = []
        self.text = []

with open('text1.txt', "r+") as f:
    # so specific lines can be edited
    lines = f.readlines()

    groups = collections.defaultdict(Group)
    group_pattern = re.compile(r'^(\S+)\((.*)\)$')
    current_group = None

    for line in range(len(lines)):
        curr_line = lines[line]

        # to prevent searches on lines with no group
        if "(" in curr_line:
            curr_line = curr_line.strip()
            m = group_pattern.match(curr_line)
            if m:
                group_name, group_members = m.groups()
                groups[group_name].members += filter(lambda x: x not in groups[group_name].members, group_members.split(','))
                current_group = group_name

    already_seen = []
    for line in range(len(lines)):
        curr_line = lines[line]

        for key in groups.keys():
            if key in curr_line.strip():
                if key in already_seen:
                    lines[line] = ""
                else:
                    already_seen.append(key)
                    open_par = curr_line.index("(")
                    close_par = curr_line.index(")")

                    member_str = ",".join(groups[key].members)

                    lines[line] = curr_line[:open_par+1] + member_str + curr_line[close_par:]

    # clear the file and reset the file cursor
    f.truncate()
    f.seek(0)

    for line in lines:
        f.write(line)
```

Comment: no words to say absolutely fantastic,i have less scores i cant rate you.but the much awaited best answer.Thank you so much!Sorry for late replies!

Answer (score 1):

As you can read in the [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects), open the file using `open` and the modifier `w` to truncate the file and allow writes, then write to the file:

```
with open('text1.txt', 'w') as f:
    for group_name, group in groups.items():
        f.write("%s(%s)" % (group_name, ','.join(group.members)))
        f.write('\n'.join(group.text) + '\n')
```

You could also open the file a single time using `r+` to allow read and write and change your code like this:

```
with open('text1.txt', 'r+') as f:
    groups = ...
    ...
    ...         groups[current_group].text.append(line)

    f.seek(0)             # move the cursor to the beginning of the file
    f.truncate()          # deletes everything from the file

    for group_name, group in groups.items():
        f.write("%s(%s)" % (group_name, ','.join(group.members)))
        f.write('\n'.join(group.text) + '\n')
```

Comment: its changing some indentation that affects my output!is there a way to solve that?so it should be same as print stmt output?

Comment: yes,but again the problem is its changing the indentation.How can i preserve the lines and indentation even by changing the output?

Comment: Well, if the problem is this, your question is worded wrongly, you asked how to write to file, by the way the indentation should be the same, both `print` and `write` deals with string, one is printing to the console and the other to file. Could you please show some example?